# Node.js and socket.io timer reset

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

hi Guys how can i reset my timer to 10 sec when my timer turns to 0 below is my code. What happen in my current code it doesnt restart to zero when i declare in the connection.

`app.js :`

```
countdown = 10;
var onInterval = function() {
    countdown--;
    if(countdown == 0){
        var endTime = currTimer();

        clearInterval(myInterval);
  io.sockets.emit('timer', { timer: countdown });

};
var myInterval = setInterval(onInterval, 1000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
    socket.on('restart timer', function (data) {
         setTimeout(function(){
            countdown = 10;
            myInterval = setInterval(onInterval, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: i'm trying to do is to reset my timer to 10 sec again..I'm build an auction site I need to reset my timer after 10 sec after i have announce the winner in my auction game.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need. I don't know why do you need that setTimeout.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
    socket.on('restart timer', function (data) {
        countdown = 10;
        myInterval = setInterval(onInterval, 1000);
    }
}
```